# read.fwf reverses sign on all numbers

Tags: r

For some inexplicable reason, read.fwf is reversing the signs of all the numbers in the table I'm reading in. My code is like this:

```
person.widths <- c(6, 8, 3, 6, rep(7, 8), 6, 12)
meas <- - read.fwf(file=myfile,
                header=FALSE,
                widths=person.widths,
                colClasses=c(rep("numeric", 14)),
                na.strings='.'
                )
```

The resulting data frame looks like this:

```
head(meas)
V1    V2 V3 V4  V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10 V11   V12   V13       V14
1 -1 -3.16 -1 -6 -22 -0.79 -0.71  0.48 -0.70  0.44   0 -0.88  -236 -22227190
2 -2 -4.87 -1 -6 -24 -1.15 -1.23 -0.27 -0.96  0.03   0 -0.76  -592 -22227199
3 -3 -2.59 -1 -6 -21 -0.72 -0.32  1.39 -0.34  1.32   0 -0.90  -592 -22227200
4 -4  0.00  2  0   0  0.00 -1.00  0.00 -1.00  0.00   0  0.00  -206 -22227201
5 -5 -3.87 -1 -6 -23 -0.90 -1.49 -0.65 -1.38 -0.35   0 -0.84  -506 -22227202
6 -6 -5.72  0 -6 -25 -1.52 -1.00  0.00 -1.00  0.00   0  0.00 -5859 -22227204
```

But the original data looks like this:

```
> foo <- readLines(myfile)
> head(foo)
[1] "     1    3.16  1     6     22   0.79   0.71  -0.48   0.70  -0.44   0.00   0.88 236      22227190"
[2] "     2    4.87  1     6     24   1.15   1.23   0.27   0.96  -0.03   0.00   0.76 592      22227199"
[3] "     3    2.59  1     6     21   0.72   0.32  -1.39   0.34  -1.32   0.00   0.90 592      22227200"
[4] "     4    0.00 -2     0      0   0.00   1.00   0.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   0.00 206      22227201"
[5] "     5    3.87  1     6     23   0.90   1.49   0.65   1.38   0.35   0.00   0.84 506      22227202"
[6] "     6    5.72  0     6     25   1.52   1.00   0.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   0.00 5859     22227204"
```

This doesn't make any sense to me. In this case, I can use a plain read.table and it works OK, but I have no idea why the signs are switched when I use read.fwf. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

It is *of course* just a simple typo. In the line

```
meas <- - read.fwf(file=myfile,
```

you apply an explicit `* (-1)` multiplication by having that stray `-` hanging around after the `<-` assignment operator and before the actual function `read.fwf()`.

We've all been there. Good editors can help with proper colour highlighting.

Comment: Oh, my goodness! Thanks, Dirk. I knew something so random had to be something dumb I was doing.